# Can the radius of convergence of a sum of two power series be an arbitrary number?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, analytic-functions

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n,\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ be two series with the same radius convergence $R>0$. Can the radius of convergence of their sum be any positive real number which is greater than $R$?

Comment: Well, it seems to be obvious that the convergence radius of a sum of two series is *at least* the minimum of both series' radiuses...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to limit the possible values to be greater than $R$.

Comment: Take a series with $a_n=0$ for $n$ even. It seems you can take $b_n=-a_n$ for $n$ odd and select $b_n$ with $n$ even appropriately to get what you want.

Comment: Do you require any restriction on the kind of coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can. If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $R\in(0,\infty)$, and if $r>R$, consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-a_n+r^{-n})z^n$, whose radius of convergence is also $R$. But the radius of convergence of the sum of both series is $r$.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see a way to prove that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-a_n+r^{-n})z^n$  is also $R$ using the  Cauchy–Hadamard theorem?

Comment: Right now, I cannot. But note that if $\lvert z\rvert<R$, then the series is the sum of two convergent series and therefore it converges. So, the radius of convergence is *at least* $R$. And if $R<\lvert z\rvert<r$, then the series is the sum of a convergent series with a divergent one, and therefore it diverges. So, the radius of convergence is *at most* $R$. Conclusion: the radius of convergence *is* $R$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you! That was my argument as well; I guess this is easier than using the Cauchy–Hadamard formula.

Comment: @AsafShachar for the sake of completeness, a calculation of the radius of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-a_n+r^{-n})z^n$ done by using the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem is the following: we have $$\sqrt[n]{\left| -a_n +\frac{1}{r^n}\right|}=\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\sqrt[n]{\left| 1-\frac{1}{r^n|a_n |}\right|}.$$ Then, since $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1/R$ we have that $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\le\frac{1+\epsilon}{R} \quad\forall n>N_\epsilon$$ and $$\sqrt[n]{\left| -a_n +\frac{1}{r^n}\right|}\le\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\sqrt[n]{\left| 1-\frac{R^n}{r^n|1+\epsilon|^n}\right|}.$$ (...continues in the following comment).

Comment: @AsafShachar ...and remembering that $R<r$ we have that $$\frac{1}{R}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left| -a_n +\frac{1}{r^n}\right|}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\sqrt[n]{\left| 1-\frac{R^n}{r^n|1+\epsilon|^n}\right|}=\frac{1}{R}.$$